# Submit form in jquery popup box/window

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

How can I submit a form with POST data to a jQuery pop box/window and show it on the same page? My form will submit to a new page called `results.php`.

Comment: have you considered using AJAX for this ?

Comment: $.post(url, postvar, function(data){ dialog.append(data) })